# C# 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' for one array but not another

Tags: c#, indexing, bounds

I have 2 arrays for storing 2 series of inputs from the user. I set the bounds for both arrays to be equal to the same variable, but when inputting the info, after the final input on the first array, i get an exception 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'.

When i tried to change the bounds of the arrays to constant numbers, they were behaving normally.

```
            string[] names = new string[movies-1];
            double[] ratings = new double[movies-1];
            for(int i = 0; i < movies; i++)
            {
                names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                ratings[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }
```

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: The only reason you're not getting an exception on the other one is because the program stops after the first exception. If you comment out the first line, you will see that the second one throws the same exception.

Comment: There are a few things you can do to help yourself too, apart from the perfectly valid answer. You could use List, given your data type and use it will have no negative impact, even on a performance side it might actually be quicker. As for finding and working the Exception, debugging properly might be something to look into for the future.

Comment: You should consider keeping related data together in a custom class or a tuple so you can have just one array of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just off by one (twice) -

1. The arrays should be instantiated to be in the length of `movies`, not  `movies-1`
2. When iterating, you want `i` to be equal to `movies-1` at most, because the array assignments start at 0.

Think about it - if `movies` is equal to 1 (one movie), you're currently instantiating an array with 0 slots - any index you try to access will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

C# exhibits *zero based indexing*. That is, an array of size `s` will have its elements indexed from `0` to `s - 1`.

Since you declared the array `names` to be of size `movies - 1`, its elements are indexed from `0` to `movies - 2`. Therefore, the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < movies; i++)
{
    names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    ratings[i] = ...
    ...
```

will try to access an out of bounds index in arrays `names` and `ratings` when `i = movies - 1`.

You should declare your arrays as:

```
string[] names = new string[movies];
double[] ratings = new double[movies];
```

so that they are consistent with your `for` loop definition.